# Xamarin: "attachable property "Header" can't be found on type "Expander" "

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xamarin, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have the following XAML:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <xct:Expander IsExpanded="true">
        <StackLayout>
            <xct:Expander.Header>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </xct:Expander.Header>
            <xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Item.Text}"/>
                <Button Text="doSomething" Command="{Binding command}"/>
            </xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </xct:Expander>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And I get this error when compiling:

```
attachable property "Header" can't be found on type "Expander"
```

I have already installed `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit` package and added

```
     xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
```

to the namespace.

I have also cleaned and rebuilded the project several times. Nothing works.

Any idea?

Comment: why is there a `StackLayout` as the child of `Expander`?

Comment: Nice! It must be a DataTemplate. It solved for me. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `<xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>` to `StackLayout` and remove the StackLayout outside to make the stacklayout the child of the expander. Here is the demo you can refer to.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <xct:Expander IsExpanded="true">
      
            <xct:Expander.Header>
                <Label Text="name"/>
            </xct:Expander.Header>
              
        <StackLayout> 
            <Label Text="Binding Item.Text"/>
            <Button Text="doSomething" Command="{Binding command}"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </xct:Expander>
</ContentPage.Content>
```